# perl - spliting string with quoted characters

Tags: regex, perl, split

I want to split the following string at the pipe character without split at the escaped pipe:

```
"123|ABC|x\|yz|123"  should result in ["123","ABC","x|yz",123]
```

Does anyone had such a split regexp for perl?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookbehind:

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my $str = '123|ABC|x\|yz|123';
my @bits = split /(?<!\\)\|/, $str;

print Dumper(@bits);
```

Results in:

```
$VAR1 = '123';
$VAR2 = 'ABC';
$VAR3 = 'x\\|yz';
$VAR4 = '123';
```

As pointed out by [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew), if your string was of the form:

```
my $str = '123|ABC|x\|yz|123\\|456|123\\345';
```

The `123\\` would be grouped with `456` (athough the last string
`123\\345` would be okay):

```
$VAR1 = '123';
$VAR2 = 'ABC';
$VAR3 = 'x\\|yz';
$VAR4 = '123\\|456';
$VAR5 = '123\\345';
```

This is because the negative lookbehind only asserts a single backslash.

Comment: That's smart, I tryed with a  `[` `^\/` `]` , but that would remove the last character of each element

Comment: Unless there can also be ``\\`` in the input denoting a literal backslash, this will work.

Comment: @JohnDoe yeah, even negated character class have to match at least one character, which is why it would get consumed.